# Replace string not within one of multiple possible multiple-character enclosures

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to parse a string with JavaScript's `.replace`, *except* if it's between any of multiple pairs of delimiters. Which method of doing so is the simplest, and hopefully most general and/or efficient?

I've tried alternating the options for the left and right delimiters in my regular expression; using a callback argument in `.replace` to look up each match's two captured delimiters in a map object; and responding accordingly, but this solution **does not totally work**.

In this particular situation, I want to replace instances of `++`, followed immediately by at least one non-plus character, followed immediately by `++`, with just the enclosed text, capitalised - except if the instances are between, but not necessarily immediately preceded/followed by, `@&lt;` and `>@`, or `@@` and `@@`.

```js
var options = {
    '@&lt;': ['>@', 5, 2],
    '@@': ['@@', 2, 2]
},
possiblyParse = str => str.replace(/(@&lt;|@@|^).+?(>@|@@|$)/g, (a, b, c) =>
    options.hasOwnProperty(b) && options[b][0] == c ?
    a.slice(options[b][1], a.length - options[b][2]) : // If string suitably enclosed, return it without delimiters
    a.replace(/\+\+([^\+]+)\+\+/g, (a, b) => b.toUpperCase())); // Otherwise, do something, keeping delimiter(s) if any
console.log(possiblyParse('input'));
```

This code produces these acceptable results…

```
console.log(possiblyParse('++abc++'))); // ABC
console.log(possiblyParse('@&lt;++abc++>@')); // ++abc++
console.log(possiblyParse('@@++abc++@@')); // ++abc++
console.log(possiblyParse('@&lt;++abc++@@')); // @&lt;ABC@@
console.log(possiblyParse('@@++abc++>@')); // @@ABC>@
console.log(possiblyParse('@&lt;++abc++')); // @&lt;ABC
console.log(possiblyParse('++abc++@@')); // ABC@@
```

… and fails here:

```
console.log(possiblyParse('z@&lt;@++abc++>@')) // z@&lt;ABC>@, should be z++abc++
console.log(possiblyParse('++abc++ @&lt;@++abc++>@')) // ABC @&lt;ABC>@, should be ABC ++abc++
```

I suspect a problem with my regex, `/(@&lt;|@@|^).+?(>@|@@|$)/g`, which I think matches `@&lt;`, `@@` or the start of the input, then lazily matches at least one character, then matches `>@`, `@@` or the end of the input. Can you help resolve this?

Comment: This question should be posted on [Code Review | Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think you'd have more success getting an answer if instead of asking us to reverse-engineer your *working* code, to explain what the constraints are, what you tried, input, and expected output.

Comment: It's pretty strange to want to do *something else* in the case that a starting delimiter does not match the ending delimiter, rather than just failing entirely? I can think of a nice solution if the starting delimiter always needs to match the ending delimiter, but allowing them to *not* match and do something on the result is quite odd, are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: At approximately 2019-01-27T07:05:00Z, I found a problem with my code. Please understand that **the question has been changed**.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @melpomene: In this particular situation, I want to replace instances of `++`, followed by text, followed by `++`, with just the enclosed text, capitalised - except if the instances are between `@&lt;` and `>@`, or between `@@` and `@@`.

Comment: @dxa_kly That's ambiguous.

Comment: I've now edited the question to add a slightly clearer explanation of my goal.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at the following solution before receiving answers from other users, but if you have a better answer, do contribute it.

My solution simply encodes each string within either of the possible delimiters such that the result contains no `++` pairs, then does capitalisation, then decodes all the encoded strings.

```js
var encodeWithOrDecode = (x, y) => y ?
    (a, b) => x + b.replace(/./g, // Callback to replace each character to be encoded with...
        e => '<' + e.charCodeAt().toString(36) + '<') + y : // ... its number, in base 36, between '<' and '<'
    (c, d) => d.replace(/<(\w+)</g, (a, b) => String.fromCharCode(parseInt(b, 36))); // Callback to decode each portion of string to be decoded
console.log('++just got up++|@&lt;feeling down>@|@@in the dumps@@'
    .replace(/@&lt;(.+?)>@/g, encodeWithOrDecode('@&lt;', '>@')).replace(/@@(.+?)@@/g, encodeWithOrDecode('@@', '@@')) // Encodes text to be left raw
    .replace(/\+\+([^\+]+)\+\+/g, (a, b) => b.toUpperCase()) // Capitalises only text to be parsed
    .replace(/@&lt;(.+?)>@/g, encodeWithOrDecode()).replace(/@@(.+?)@@/g, encodeWithOrDecode())); // Decodes text to be left raw
```

**Explanation**

`/@&lt;(.+?)>@/g` or `/@@(.+?)@@/g` will match all instances of the relevant delimiters that have text in between.

- The left delimiter (respectively `@&lt;` or `@@`) is matched literally
- The capturing group matches at least one non-line-terminating character, as few times as possible
- The right delimiter (respectively `>@` or `@@`) is matched literally

Where the two regular expressions above are used in `.replace`, the callback in the same function, returned by `encodeWithOrDecode`, takes the matches as parameters. The second such parameter is what's in the capturing group, and gets encoded or decoded.